# Laravel searching query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, search-engine

I am implementing search feature, I have a column `search_words` in `users` table, where `search_words` populates when a new insertion is made to other(three) tables with space between keyword, Like

```
search_words
------------
john dotaChamp gammer
David English education
```

Now the question is that how can i search all three tables on the basis of visitor search, Right now i am just querying only one table `users`. Like this :

`$results = App\User::where('username','LIKE',"%$query%")->get();`

Comment: can you use joins and use multiple where conditions connected with "orWhere"?

Comment: @herrjeh42 An example will be great .

Comment: Additional note: I am asking myself why you are duplicating the keywords multiple times. Can you introduce a new table keywords and store them only once? This is more "relational database design style" and solves your search problem as well.

Comment: @herrjeh42 The search keywords stores for each user. That helps in searching.